# Upgrade TYPO3 to a specific version

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am new to TYPO3 and tried to install the official introduction package.
I found the package in the extension manager and clicked install but got the following message:

```
Could not install distribution 'bootstrap_package'
Your TYPO3 version is lower than this extension requires. It requires TYPO3 versions 6.2.14 - 7.99.99
```

I am using TYPO3 version 6.2.11.
I installed the system via docker [TYPO3-docker-boilerplate](https://github.com/webdevops/TYPO3-docker-boilerplate).
I think this tool uses composer to get the TYPO3 base distribution.
I tried the upgrade wizard but there was no option to choose a specific version to upgrade to. So how can I upgrade TYPO3 to version 6.2.14?

I need to use version 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the cms-base-distribution Composer package hasn't been updated since March. So you have to set the `typo3/cms` package in the `composer.json` file to the version you need (latest stable version of 6.2 is 6.2.15). The file is located in the `code` directory.

Then run `composer update` in the same directory.

This should update one dependency and the `cms` package itself:

```
- Removing helhum/class-alias-loader (1.0.99)
- Installing helhum/class-alias-loader (1.1.5)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing typo3/cms (6.2.11)
- Installing typo3/cms (6.2.15)
  Downloading: 100%
```